How to count all the files that exist in folder and its sub-folders using ADF pipeline
I have an azure file share directory with files, folders and files within the folders
FOLDER1 -- file1, file2, file3 ...
FILE1
FILE2
FOLDER2 - file1, file2 ...
FOLDER3 - file1, file2, file3 ....
I would like to develope a pipeline that counts all the files within the file share folder itself and files within the folders.
My solution so far:
I used Get Metadata activity to list all the childitems, but I am stuck on what next to do. I am a beginner with azure.

are the files exists only in the last subfolder or in any parent or intermediate folder as well?

The files exist  in any parent or intermediate folder as well


How to count all the files that exist in folder and its sub-folders using ADF pipeline

To count files from the folder and its sub folder you need to use the combination of getmetadata , filter and for each loop activity as below:


First use Get metadata activity to get child items from the file share directory.
Then use filter activity to filter the files and folders using the output of get metadata


For folders - @equals(item().type,'Folder')
For files - @equals(item().type,'files')


Then pass the output of filter activity where you filter the folders pass to the for each loop.
The similarly get File numbers from subfolders in foreach loop as above and the store it in the append variable.

Then take for each loop to Add the subfolders file count stored in append variable pass it to this for each loop:
Then take two variablessubfilecount and subfilecounttemp to add the subfolders files as below:


Then add this count and directory files count which we separated from first get metdata output:


My pipelie.json:
{
    "name": "pipeline3",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Get Metadata1",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText2",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "childItems"
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Filter1",
                "type": "Filter",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "condition": {
                        "value": "@equals(item().type,'Folder')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Filter2",
                "type": "Filter",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "condition": {
                        "value": "@equals(item().type,'File')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Filter1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Filter1').output.value",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Get Metadata2",
                            "type": "GetMetadata",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "DelimitedText3",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "subfoldername": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "fieldList": [
                                    "childItems"
                                ],
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                },
                                "formatSettings": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Filter3",
                            "type": "Filter",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Get Metadata2",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "items": {
                                    "value": "@activity('Get Metadata2').output.childItems",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "condition": {
                                    "value": "@equals(item().type,'Folder')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Filter4",
                            "type": "Filter",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Get Metadata2",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "items": {
                                    "value": "@activity('Get Metadata2').output.childItems",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "condition": {
                                    "value": "@equals(item().type,'File')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Append variable1",
                            "type": "AppendVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Filter4",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "subfolder files",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@activity('Filter4').output.FilteredItemsCount",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable3",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Filter2",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach2",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "subfilecounttemp",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@add(activity('Filter2').output.FilteredItemsCount,variables('subfilecount'))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach2",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@variables('subfolder files')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Set variable4",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "subfilecount",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@add(item(),variables('subfilecounttemp'))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Set variable5",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Set variable4",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "subfilecounttemp",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@variables('subfilecount')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "subfolder": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "subfolder files": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "subfilecounttemp": {
                "type": "Integer"
            },
            "fies": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "subfilecount": {
                "type": "Integer"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}

